# WPF Snap window to left edge of screen leaves gap

Tags: wpf

I need to 'snap' a WPF window to the left edge of my screen. I've tried setting the Left value to zero, but this leaves a small gap, of about 8 pixels. Does anyone know why/what this is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's the window border and its size depends on the current Windows theme so that gap could vary.

Try subtracting the current Non-Client Frame thickness:

```
myWindow.Left = 0.0 - SystemParameters.WindowNonClientFrameThickness.Left;
```

Comment: That's the one. Thanks!